# Checking if treeview contains an item

Tags: c#, wpf

This problem seems simple enough. I have a treeview, let's call it MyTreeView, populated with all of the drive letters, so the treeview looks like this: 
A:\ 
C:\ 
D:\ 
F:\

How do I check if the treeview contains a specific item? How does the treeview identify its items?
I have created a MessageBox to show MyTreeView.Items.GetItemAt(1), and it identifies item 1 as: 
"System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem Header:C:\ Items.Count:1"

Try the easiest thing first, which obviously doesn't work:

```
if (MyTreeView.Items.Contains(@"C:\")
{
    MessageBox.Show(@"Tree contains C:\");
}
```

The next easiest thing would be to try making a TreeViewItem that looks similar to what I want, which also doesn't work:

```
TreeViewItem myItem = new TreeViewItem();
myItem.Header = @"C:\";
if (MyTreeView.Items.Contains(myItem)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Tree contains " + myItem.ToString());
}
```

Just to make sure I had the fundamental concept right, I tried some circular logic, which actually does work:

```
var myItem = MyTreeView.Items.GetItemAt(1);
if (MyTreeView.Items.Contains(myItem)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Tree contains " + myItem.ToString());
}
```

Which outputs: 
"Tree contains System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem Header:C:\ Items.Count:1"

What am I doing wrong? How do I check if my tree contains something like "C:\" ?

edit: 
The code for building the tree is this: 
(basically a copy and paste from the internet)

```
        foreach (string myString in Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
        {
            TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
            item.Header = myString;
            item.Tag = myString;
            item.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            item.Items.Add(dummyNode); // this is (object)dummyNode = null
            item.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(DWGFolder_Expanded);
            item.Selected += new RoutedEventHandler(DWGFolder_Selected);
            // the Expanded event is very similar, 
            // subitem.Header is the folder name (Testing),
            // while subitem.Tag is the full path (C:\Testing)
            MyTreeView.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

So basically I'm trying to match TreeViewItem objects.

Comment: The reason your second doesn't work is that your TreeView obviously won't contain an item you just created. Your third method is very close. You said it works, why not keep building on it?

Comment: You could assign the Object in your treeview a name and then use `.FindName` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe .Contains() would check for the value by reference since it isn't a simple string object. This requires you to iterate through each of the items until you retrieve the item which matches the header.

LINQ Example

```
    if (MyTreeView.Items.Cast<TreeViewItem>().Any(item => item.Header.ToString() == @"C:\"))
    {
       MessageBox.Show(@"Tree contains C:\");
    }
```

Comment: **"I believe .Contains() would check for the value by reference"** 

Interesting. I didn't think of it that way, but that makes sense.

Anyway, your solution works flawlessly. Thank you so much!

Comment: If the itemCollection contains a value type like string it would be fine just checking for the "newValue".
Glad I could help.

Comment: @lamorach String is not a value type, even if it behaves as such. But now that you mention it, I guess the equality comparers would work with `Contains` in that case. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

`Contains` looks for the exact same instance inside the collection. If you don't have the object you want to check already, you can't use `Contains`.

But you can use some basic LINQ query... Add the LINQ namespace to your class:

```
using System.Linq;
```

If your items are indeed just Strings, then use this query (**EDIT** - Though, in case they're just Strings, `Contains` *should* work, since their equality comparers don't behave like those of regular reference types, but compare by value):

```
if (MyTreeView.Items.Cast<string>().Any(s => s == @"C:\"))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

If your items are TreeViewItems, you can use this one:

```
if (MyTreeView.Items.Cast<TreeViewItem>().Any(i => i.Header.ToString() == @"C:\"))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

But your items could be any class we don't know, or your header binding could change... Without knowing how you're adding the items to the TreeView, it's hard to give you the best alternative.

**EDIT** - Keep in mind that this will only search in the first level of the tree. If the item you're looking for is placed somewhere deeper, you'll have to do a recursive search. At that point, maybe just keeping the values stored somewhere from the start would be better.

Comment: i think you should check string with header of items. otherwise it wont work.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because "Unable to cast object of type System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem to type System.String"
but I think you're on the right track. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Items doesn't return a list of TreeViewItems, it returns the actual data. That's why I said "if your items are indeed just Strings". They could also be a completely different class, for that matter...

Comment: @ShawnCarinchuck Could you add to your question the piece of code where you're actually adding the items to the TreeView?

Comment: Thanks for all the help; you've given me a lot to think about. I foolishly assumed a TreeView could only contain TreeViewItems. The compiler not making that assumption would explain why it has no idea what I'm trying to do.
Your solution works great!

Comment: You're welcome! Just to extend a bit more: In WPF, TreeView, ComboBox, ListBox... all inherit from ItemsControl. The `Items` property comes from there, and you can add any kind of object to it. Derived controls like TreeView internally wrap those objects around their own "item container" (TreeViewItem, in this case), unless you're actually adding an object of the same type of the "item container", like you're doing. But the object in the `Items` collection remains the same type it was when you added it, anyway, be it a String, a TreeViewItem or any other class.